# Htaccess - Redirect by referrer

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to redirect referrer to the *homepage* that are linking to a part of my website that is not meant to be public. (*http://www.example.com/my-private-page.html* **redirect to**  *http://www.example.com*)

How can I do that with .htaccess?

Comment: So it's now meant to be public?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^my-private-page$ / [R]
```

This will need you to install mod_rewrite by the way, but it's probably already installed unless you are hosting the website yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(http://www.example.com/)my-private-page $1 [L]
```

Or is my-private-page a folder? Then put a htaccess file with simple redirect inside that folder

Answer (score 0):

With this for the referrer:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} example\.com [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} example\.net [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} example\.org 
RewriteRule ^my-private-page$ /
```

Alternately, you could do that like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} yourstring\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my-private-page.html
RewriteRule /*$ http://www.example.com/ [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match against an HTTP_REFERER using apache variable %{HTTP_REFERER} in mod_rewrite.

Here I am providing an easy soulution to redirect a http_referer to a diffrent page on the site.

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^protected_page\.html$ /another_page.html [NC,L,R]
```

The RewriteCond checks if the HTTP_REFERER is not **mydomain.com** then redirect the request **/protected_page.html** to **/another_page.html** .

The code will work in your root/htaccess file, just replace mydoman.com with your domainname.